# How to specify a folder for a System.Diagnostics listener or filter in the xml?

Tags: c#, .net, prism, trace, system.diagnostics

we are working in a Prism application developing some modules that are deployed in a sub folder called Modules loaded by the bootstraper.

Now we need to deploy a new listener to write traces using `System.Diagnostics.Tracing`. This is how the app.config looks after we added our listener:

```
<sources>
  <source name="SourceName" switchValue="Information">
    <listeners>
      <add name="TextWriter" type="ListenerClassName, AssemblyName" initializeData="log.txt">
        <filter type="FilterClassName, AssemblyName"  />
      </add>
      <remove name="Default" />
    </listeners>
  </source>
</sources>
```

As we only develop modules we cannot deploy anything in the application folder. Is there a way to tell to the System.Diagnostics API where to find our AssemblyName?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you can only add the listener by code, in some static method that is called _automatically_ when your module is loaded.

Comment: Yes, this is one way, but I was hoping to be able to maintain the capabilities of letting the configuration to the end user thru the xml ... anyway it's worth a try, thanks.

Comment: @kennyzx: please add the comment as an answer as we found a mixed approach that works thanks to your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can only add the listener by code, in some static method that is called automatically when your module is loaded.

Comment: This is the approach the are following as nothing better was found.